# How to manage onClick event of a row field in DetailsList(UI Fabric)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, fabric

I want to catch the event when click in a row field of a DetailsList in Webpart.
My code looks like :

```
return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div className="ms-Grid">   
            <div className="ms-Grid-row">
              <DetailsList
                items={_items}
                columns={this.state.columns}
                setKey='set'
                onRenderItemColumn={this._renderItemColumn}
                onColumnHeaderClick={this._onColumnClick.bind(this)}
                onItemInvoked={(item, index) => alert(`Item ${item.name} at index ${index} has been invoked.`)}
                onColumnHeaderContextMenu={(column, ev) => console.log(`column ${column.key} contextmenu opened.`)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
.....

private _renderItemColumn(item, index, column) {
    let fieldContent = item[column.fieldName];
    switch (column.key) {
      case 'file':
        return <Link onClick={this._onColumnClickView.bind(item)} id={item['id']}>{fieldContent}</Link>
      default:
        return <span >{fieldContent}</span>;
    }
  }

....
private _onColumnClickView(ev, column) {
    console.log(column);
// your code here
  }
```

But it doesn't work. The Link doesn't display. I changed the code to:

```
private _renderItemColumn(item, index, column) {
        let fieldContent = item[column.fieldName];
        switch (column.key) {
          case 'file':
            return <Link onClick={this._onColumnClickView.bind(this)} id={item['id']}>{fieldContent}</Link>
          default:
            return <span >{fieldContent}</span>;
        }
      }
```

But nothing changes.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try

```
onClick={(event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   this._onColumnClickView(this);
}
```

Comment: Its not working

Comment: @Blocfos - did you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

you can actually put it directly this way

```
onClick={this._onColumnClickView}
```

the _onColumnClickView function will still know the event.

```
private _onColumnClickView = (event) =>{  
 console.log("event",event) 
}
```

Hope it helps somehow. Happy SharePointing!